# Can't get Drag & Rearrange ListView for Xamarin Android to work

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

pnavk created a Drag and Rearanging listview: http://www.pranavkhandelwal.com/blog/2014/12/26/drag-rearrange-listview-for-xamarin-android Since this is what I need for my app, I am trying to get it to work, but I'm stuck.

I Downloaded the code and setup an empty Android project. Created a xaml file with a LinearLayout and a ListView.

Two problems occur:

1. hit exception at MainActivity line 25:

   > System.MissingMethodException: No constructor found for DraggableListView.DraggableListView::.ctor(System.IntPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership).

Resolved this by creating "public DraggableListView(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer) { }"

So far so good... but the next one is really puzzling me.

2. Listview shows no response to long presses, flings, etc. Already found that due to the new constructor init is not called. Every effort of calling the DragggableListView::init leads to crashes in the App.

Can you help out?

Comment: Already found the following in the output: `JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to pass an instance of android.widget.ListView as argument 1 to void android.view.GestureDetector.<init>(android.view.GestureDetector$OnGestureListener)`, but still no clue how to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution by myself.

The solution: not use a ListView in the axml, but refer to the DraggableListView in your apps namespace. Note that you must specify the namespace here in lowercase.

> appnamespace.ui.android.extensions.DraggableListView

So in my case the axml now look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <appnamespace.ui.android.extensions.DraggableListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/playerListView" />
</LinearLayout>
```